# PayPal sandbox email notifications

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm testing PayPal as a payment method for my website in sandbox mode. My requirement is, an email must be send to the merchant after each transaction. I am using the PHP SDK. How is this possible?

This is the configuration that I have seen for notifications in paypal.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PayPal already sends its own emails to the merchants after each transaction completes. In sandbox, you can see the notification methods in the "Notifications" tab of https://developer.paypal.com

If you want to generate your own emails in addition to the PayPal emails, you should use a server-side integration.  Here is the front-end UI: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

You'll need two corresponding routes on your server, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/

That last route of yours can send your email on success.

Comment: In https://developer.paypal.com, in "Notifications" tab , I can see some invoices. But I am not receiving the email, where I am the merchant? Is it because, I am using sandbox account??. When comes to real paypal live environment, does the email sending to merchant happens by default?

Comment: I have edited my question. Added an image which shows the configuration in the paypal for notifications.

Comment: Sandbox does not send emails, and all email addresses in sandbox are completely fictitious. Messages appear in the Notifications section of developer

Comment: So when in the live paypal environment, we did not have to do any additonal configurations like IPN setting and all, for sending emails to merchant, right??

Comment: PayPal sends its own email notifications by default, which look just like what you see previewed in the Notifications section